# Removing empty strings in Java - unexpected empty sentence: [] issue

Tags: java, string

I want to remove all digits, punctuation and trailing white spaces from a text similar to this from a JSON file (take input from the documents key and output the cleaned text into the lemmas key).

```
{"documents":{"doc803":" 1.8","doc14":" No Frames","doc810":" reducer - a commutative associative combining function","doc244":" Since:","doc486":" true if the value was replaced","doc245":" 1.6","doc487":" Throws:",...}, "lemmas":{...}}
```

I have tried this:

```
    private String LemmatiseSingleDocument(String text) {
        // transforms the text removing spaces, punctuation, digits and converting to the lower case.

        text = text.replaceAll("\\p{Punct}", " ");
        text = text.replaceAll("\\d+"," ");
        text = text.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");        
        text = text.trim();
        text = text.toLowerCase();

        // then save the words into the lemmas key
        Sentence sentence = new Sentence(text);
        List<String> lemmas = sentence.lemmas();
        text = String.join(" ", lemmas);
        System.out.println(text);
        return text;

    }
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: unexpected empty sentence: []
```

Now if I try `text.replaceAll("\\d."," ");` there are no errors, but the second part of the number, e.g. '8' or '6' remains.

It does look like I cannot remove '1.5' or '1.8' because it is like a  single sentence - so after running `replaceAll("\\d+"," ")` it becomes an empty string and encounters this error.

How can I remove all empty strings like that before feeding them into my Sentence object?

I have also tried `text.replaceAll("\\n\\d"," ")` with `\\n` for newline with no success.

Comment: ```"\\d."``` is one digit followed by one character

Comment: Doing manipulation of structured data using unstructured tooling is almost always a mistake. You want to read this in with some JSON library, go through each and every String value and fix the raw string inside directly, and then export the end result back out as JSON. As a trivial example, keys in JSON can (and shuold) be string, and you presumably don't want to mess with them. JSON can contain numbers, surely you dont want to turn '{"size": 1.0}` into `"size": 10}`, and if you don't think that's invalid input, surely you want an error stating so, instead of a silent conversion to garbage.

Comment: As a more practical point, 'replace all punctuation means that e.g. `"doc803": " 1.8"` turns into `"doc803"  "1.8"` (colon gone), surely you did not want that. Once you start on 'I want colons inside string quotes to go away but elsewhere not' this becomes very difficult, given that `\"` (quote escape) is a thing. Hence: __do not use regexes for this, use a JSON parser first__.

Comment: If this is a legitimate thing to do in the first place, what you need to do is to **post the actual value** of the replaced string and tell us why and in what way it's wrong.